# How to add a delete button to a PHP form that will delete a row from a MySQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have outputted the results of a MySQL table to an HTML table. In the last column, I want to add a delete option which calls another form and deletes the user from the MySQL table. I can't seem to get it to work though.

This is my code for the results page:

```
<?php
                    
    $contacts = mysql_query("
        SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY ID ASC") or die( mysql_error() );
    
    // If results
    if( mysql_num_rows( $contacts ) > 0 )
    ?>
    
    <table id="contact-list">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Telephone</th>
                <th>Address</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        
        <?php while( $contact = mysql_fetch_array( $contacts ) ) : ?>
        
        

            <tr>
                <td class="contact-name"><?php echo $contact['name']; ?></td>
                <td class="contact-email"><?php echo $contact['email']; ?></td>
                <td class="contact-telephone"><?php echo $contact['telephone']; ?></td>
                <td class="contact-address"><?php echo $contact['address']; ?></td>
                <td class="contact-delete"><form action='delete.php' method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
</form></td>                
            </tr>
            
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and, this is my delete.php script

```
<?php

//Define the query
$query = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE name={$_POST['name']} LIMIT 1";

//sends the query to delete the entry
mysql_query ($query);

if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) { 
//if it updated
?>

            <strong>Contact Has Been Deleted</strong><br /><br />
    
<?php
 } else { 
//if it failed
?>
    
            <strong>Deletion Failed</strong><br /><br />
    

<?php
} 
?>
```

I cannot figure out why this is not working.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to pass a variable in the delete link. You have to pass `<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>` (the `name` value) in a hidden field or pass this value in `URL`:

**Replace**

```
<td class="contact-delete">
      <form action='delete.php' method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value="">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
      </form>
</td>
```

**With**

```
<td class="contact-delete">
    <form action='delete.php?name="<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>"' method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
    </form>
</td>
```

Comment: Oh, but I took on board the other comments and changed 'name' to 'id' :)

Comment: Why is the form action changed? Won't adding a hidden input tag suffice? (I used this when the PHP was on the same page). Are things different when sending it to another page? @devang-rathod

Answer (score 2):

USe javascript

```
<input name="Submit2" type="button" class="button" onclick="javascript:location.href='delete.php?id=<?php echo $your_id;?>';" value="&laquo; Back" />
```

and in delet.php

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

and put $id in your sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to pass name in this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="">
```

You need to have something (`<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>`) in the `value` attribute.

BTW, do not use deprecated [`mysql_*`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) functions, use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="">
```

You are missing a value which wil be picked up by this line in your delete file.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE name={$_POST['name']} LIMIT 1";
```

Right now it isn't receiving anything, which is why it will not work.

So add a value to it and it will work. Example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not write the code in that way; the code has no protection against [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

**1.** Try to use primary IDs instead of using a `name` (what happens if 2 people has the same name?).

So, you can create a hidden field to know which 'person' you are dealing with.

```
<input type="hidden" name="contact_id" value="<?php $contact['contact_id']; ?>">
```

**2.** Sanitize variables to avoid attacks:

```
<?php $contact_id = isset($_POST['contact_id'])?intval($_POST['contact_id']):0;

// proceed with the query
if($contact_id>0) { $query = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE contact_id = '$contact_id'";

}

// redirect to the main table with header("location: main.php");

?>
```