# PHP delete button for every row / change value in table for this row

Tags: php, mysql

I want there is a delete button in every row in table and when click the button for example in row 1 then the row 1 deleted.

and **EXTRA** if you know how instead of delete, when I press the button a value in the table changes. For example when click delete btn then value "OK" in table change to "DELETED".

The code work right for the specific id that put in delete.php file.

*I'm not interested in database security I just want to find a way to make it work.*

index.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "userform";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT name, email, code, status, lname, checkin, checkout, mnumber, totalprice, rescode FROM usertable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '
<table>
<tr>
<td>Fullname</td>
<td>', $row['name'] . $row['lname'], '</td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
<td>Email address</td>
<td>', $row['email'], '</td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
<td>Reservation ID</td>
<td>', $row['rescode'], '</td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
<td>Check-in</td>
<td>', $row['checkin'], '</td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
<td>Check-out</td>
<td>', $row['checkout'], '</td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
<td>Mobile number</td>
<td>', $row['mnumber'], '</td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
<td>Total price</td>
<td>', $row['totalprice'], '</td>

<td><a href="delete.php">Cancel</a></td>
</tr>

</table>';
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>

<script>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "userform";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT name, email, code, status, lname, checkin, checkout, mnumber, totalprice, rescode FROM usertable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


$sql = "DELETE FROM usertable WHERE id='10'";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
  } else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
  }

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: you should select the ids also add this id a hidden field or put as parameter button in the form.

Comment: For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144846/add-delete-button-to-php-results-table or https://www.11zon.com/zon/php/php-mysql-delete-row-button.php or

Comment: I tried but they do not work. Do you have something to suggest me for the above code.

Comment: the eaxample show what i mentioned in my first comment. You can make a get and a delete ling with a button first example and the code to delete is in the second. you have everysthing you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Query

This query:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, email, code, status, lname, checkin, checkout, mnumber, totalprice, rescode FROM usertable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

should be

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, email, code, status, lname, checkin, checkout, mnumber, totalprice, rescode FROM usertable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

## Delete link

This html code

```
<td><a href="delete.php">Cancel</a></td>
```

should be

```
<td><a href="delete.php?id=' .  $row['id'] .  '">Cancel</a></td>
```

> Please, ... check your code: you concat strings using "," instead of ".".

## Finally

This SQL code

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM usertable WHERE id='10'";
```

should be

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM usertable WHERE id='" . $_GET['id'] . "'";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are very understandable. It works!

Answer (score 1):

try this:
in index.php,

- add 'id' in sql.
  $sql = "SELECT id, name, email, code, status, lname, checkin, checkout,
  mnumber, totalprice, rescode FROM usertable";
- than pass the id in cancel link, i.e. href="delete.php?id=".$row['id']

in delete.php,
add this line $id= $GET['id'];
and pass $id to delete query,
$sql = "DELETE FROM usertable WHERE id=$id";